# Jmeter - Calculating ramp-up period

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to send **1100 requests per minutes** to my API endpoint for a period of **5 minutes**, so in total I will make 5500 requests to the endpoint.

In another words, I am trying to send **1 request every 0.054 millisecond** for a total duration **for 5 minutes**.

Based on the above requirement, Here is how I have setup my Jmeter:
[image]

It seems like I have misconfigured Jmeter, because at the end I can see Jmeter has made **8401** requests to the api instead of **5500**.

What have I missed in the configuration?

Does the **Infinite** check-box needs to be checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to send 1100 requests per minutes to my API endpoint for a period of 5 minutes, so in total I will make 5500 requests to the endpoint.

I don't know how you came with this `5500` number but this is not very correct.

Your setup means that:

1. JMeter will add 18 virtual users each second for 60 seconds
2. After 60 seconds pass JMeter will run 1100 users for another 4 minutes

The total number of requests JMeter will be able to make will mostly depend on **application response time**.

If you want to limit JMeter's throughput to 1100 requests per minute consider using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

If you don't want to limit JMeter's throughput but want 5500 executions either:

- Set "Loop Count" to 5 (but in that case you [might fail to get 1100 concurrent users](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected/))
- Or use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) in `Total Executions` mode so JMeter would stop after executing 5500 requests